# Does redis have documents and collections?

Tags: redis

I am new to redis. I am coming from mongodb. I have read on the [data types redis supports](https://redis.io/topics/data-types). I was wondering does redis group its data in documents and does it have collections?

I have seen that you can have different databases in the same redis server [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#usage-example) where you can select database 3 instead of the default 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does redis group its data in documents

No, Redis is not a document DB, meaning you can't have searches and aggregations like you did with mongo, redis offers alternatives sometimes though...

> does it have collections

Redis offers various data structures (including lists, sets, hashes, etc) that can be queried. So given you have a set of elements you can query whether the element is in the set, add the element to the set, etc.

> I have seen that you can have different databases in the same redis server here where you can select database 3 instead of the default 0.

You can think about databases in redis as "pre-defined" schemas/databases in mongo db So yes, you can say like "I would like to work with DB Number 3 and not with DB number 0. In  mongo and RDBMS you connect to schema/database by name instead

All-in-all I think you shouldn't try to think about Redis as an alternative to Mongo, its another tool designed for other use cases. Make sure you understand the laws of data modeling in Redis and the fact that Redis is more "Memory" oriented, its not a persistent DB like Mongo, Postgres, etc.